# Cypher query, format/group return values

Tags: json, node.js, neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to format the return values from a cypher query? If I do a query that returns a node and all nodes with a relation to that node ('RETURN id(startnode), id(relationnode)') i will get an array containing each relationnode with a startnode bundled.

E.g:

```
[
    {
        relationnode: 0, 
        startnode: 1
    }, {
        relationnode: 1, 
        startnode: 1
    }
]
```

How i much rather would have it work, is to have the return values formated something like so:

```
{
    relationnode: [
        0, 1
    ],
    startnode: 1
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this, or is it just bad practice all together?
This would be very useful if i knew that there would never be more than 1 startnode.

Edit: I know i could parse it after the query, I'd much rather be able to do it in the query though.

Comment: Is this a json response?

Comment: Yes, I didn't think it mattered but i'm running my db on a node server. Hence json. Sorry for not stating that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes!  This is one of my favorite features:

```
RETURN id(startnode), COLLECT(id(relationnode))
```

Comment: Nice! Exactly what i was looking for. I really ought to read through the documentation asap. Thanks for the help Brian.